# How to load 100k + Records into progres database from a CSV file?

Tags: postgresql, bulk, load

Our project needs to load 100k+ rows into a Postgres table. We have a huge `.CSV` file with all these 100K+ rows and we need to load this data into a table effectively and quicker (may be in the form of batches so that unloaded data/batch can be revisited, corrected and loaded again).

Our project involves a Java application and we initially thought of using `JDBC`, but reading each row and committing to database slows down the application.

Please suggest if you know an approach to get this job done.

Comment: Use `COPY` or the PgJDBC `CopyManager` interface to it. Or pg_loader / pg_bulkload, but a couple of hundred thousand records isn't too much and shouldn't need that. Did you search before posting? This is asked all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COPY command for this.

See:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgres-table